# How to target a specific Cucumber Feature File (Automation Test) via Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Currently I'm using a testng.xml file to target a specific RunnerClass which would then target one or more feature files via Jenkins and in turn produce a detailed report.

Is there a way to target one feature file within Jenkins based on the name of the feature file? and in turn produce a report within Jenkins.

Comment: Is this using maven or gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I know we can run a single feature file by using cucumber.options which will override all the options you have in the @CucumberOptions annotation:***

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/features/com/automation/organization/featurefiles/Account.feature"

I do not think so there is direct option available in Jenkins for running a single feature file. However You may need to identify how to execute above command from POM.xml so things get run by POM and then Jenkins.

Comment: alternatively we can specify a specific name tag to that featyre file and then run it using `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tag_name"`

Answer (score 0):

gradle test -Dtest.config=config.$(ENV).properties -Dcucumber.options=$(Tag)

Dependency tool-Grade

Need to make some changes in Jenkins as per your make file